# Can't add property _$visited, object is not extensible using primeNG, angular 2 and @ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, primeng, ngrx

**USE CASE**

Learning Angular 2 and working in a personal project. I have datatable from PrimeNg and I would like to allow selection on it.
Using redux implementation  ngrx, my datas come from the store and display well in the datatable. But I get errors when I do selection on it.
I suspected the 2 way-binding [(selection)] from the datatable component but I still get error even with only one way [selection].
Do you guys have any idea how to stop event propagation in angular 2, especially event generated by primeng framework?

When debugging, I can see the format of this event object, how can I stop the event propagation?

```
data:Object
originalEvent:Object
checked:true
originalEvent:MouseEvent
__proto__:Object
type:"checkbox"
__proto__:Object
```

**ERROR**

```
core.umd.js?e2a5:3010 TypeError: Can't add property _$visited, object is not extensible
    at DomHandler.equals (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:578:2), <anonymous>:254:28)
    at DataTable.isSelected (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:656:2), <anonymous>:600:45)
    at _View_DataTable50.detectChangesInternal (/DataTableModule/DataTable/component.ngfactory.js:4074:198)
    at _View_DataTable50.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9305:18)
    at _View_DataTable50.DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9410:48)
    at _View_DataTable49.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9323:23)
    at _View_DataTable49.detectChangesInternal (/DataTableModule/DataTable/component.ngfactory.js:3962:8)
    at _View_DataTable49.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9305:18)
    at _View_DataTable49.DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9410:48)
    at _View_DataTable0.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9323:23)
    at _View_DataTable0.detectChangesInternal (/DataTableModule/DataTable/component.ngfactory.js:201:8)
    at _View_DataTable0.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9305:18)
    at _View_DataTable0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9410:48)
    at _View_FinancialaccountbookComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9331:23)
    at _View_FinancialaccountbookComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AccountbookModule/FinancialaccountbookComponent/component.ngfactory.js:305:8)
    at _View_FinancialaccountbookComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:9305:18)
```

**DATABLE HTML**

```
  <p-dataTable [value]="flows$ | async" sortMode="multiple" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500px" [(selection)]="selectedFlows$ | async"
        scrollWidth="100%" [style]="{'margin-top':'30px', 'box-shadow': '2px 2px 5px grey'}" [responsive]="true" [styleClass]="shaddow-effect"
        (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
        <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        <footer>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let flow of selectedFlows$ | async" style="text-align: left">{{flow.id + ' - ' + flow.date + ' - ' + flow.payee + ' - ' + flow.category}}</li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </p-dataTable>
```

**DATABLE TS**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'financialaccountbook',
    templateUrl: './financial-accountbook.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [FinancialflowService]
})
export class FinancialaccountbookComponent implements OnInit {

    cols: any[];
    flows$: Observable<FLOW[]>;
    flows:FLOW[];
    selectedFlows$: Observable<FLOW[]>;
    selectedFlows:FLOW[];
    nonselected: boolean;
    msgs: Message[];
    changeLog: string[] = [];


    constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>, private financialflowService: FinancialflowService) { 
        this.flows$ = this.store.let(fromRoot.getFLows);
        this.selectedFlows$ = this.store.let(fromRoot.getSelectedFlows);

        // subscribe
        this.flows$.subscribe(v_flows=>this.flows = v_flows);
        this.selectedFlows$.subscribe(selectedflows => this.selectedFlows = selectedflows);

    }


    isFlowsSelected(): boolean {
        return (this.selectedFlows$) ? true : false;

    }

    selectionChange(selectedflows:FLOW[])
    {
         console.log(selectedflows);
        this.store.dispatch(new Actions.SelectAction(selectedflows.map(flow=>flow.id.toString())));
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        // fetch columns
        this.cols = FINANCIAL_FLOWS_COLS;
        // load flows
        this.loadFlows();

    console.log(this.selectedFlows);
    console.log(this.flows);
  //  this.flows$.subscribe(flows => console.log(flows));
    }
    loadFlows() {
        this.store.dispatch(new Actions.LoadAction());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think you might use `ngrx-store-freeze` which makes your app state non-extensible. The Datatable however uses a two way binding *[(selection)]* which modifies your state.

That's what makes store-freeze crash your app, so you could either disable store-freeze, found in the ngrx example app here: https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts#L79

Or, what might work for you as well, have a local array that is used to maintain the selected rows but not linked to the store.

Comment: Yes you nailed it. I use **ngrx-store-freeze** for my development environnment. And when I disable it works well. But  using **ngrx-store-freeze** along with local array makes crash my app. This is a bit weird as anything is linked to the store. I need to figure out how **ngrx-store-freeze** works under the hood because It looks like it freezes everything. Anyway, it helps me a lot, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Until filtering is added to ngrx-store-freeze, I use Lodash's copyDeep to "thaw" the object locally in my component:

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.AppState>) {
    //this.allApps$ = store.select("apps");
    store.let(fromRoot.getAllApps).subscribe(allApps => { this.allApps = _.cloneDeep(allApps); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue reported on PrimeNG's github relates to your question
[here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1530). You can subscribe to the thread and get updates when it will be fixed.